# Regex expression to grab value from similar text

Tags: regex

I am having some trouble figuring out the regrex expression to grab value(highlighted in bold) from similar texts. Below are some examples of the logs that i'm collecting:

> [5439570:00009-01286] 03/03/2015 10:17:31   Error checking database
>   **mail/abc**.nsf: RRV bucket is corrupt.
>
> [6946980:00002-00001] 03/14/2015 02:01:25   SchedMgr: Error
>   encountered while scanning calendar database **mail/abc.nsf** for
>   events: RRV bucket is corrupt.
>
> [8454294:00002-00001] 03/14/2015 02:01:25   RnRMgr: Error encountered
>   while scanning database **mail/abc.nsf** for events: RRV bucket is
>   corrupt.
>
> [7405822:00009-01286] 03/14/2015 00:03:04   Admin Process: Path:
>   **mail/abc.nsf:** RRV bucket is corrupt.
>
> [4260024:00002-00001] 03/14/2015 00:02:17   Unable to replicate
>   **mail/flpilshi.nsf:** RRV bucket is corrupt.
>
> [7405822:00007-00772] 03/13/2015 10:21:36   Admin Process: Path:
>   **/notes09/mail/abc.nsf:** RRV bucket is corrupt.
>
> [12714238:00002-00001] 03/13/2015 05:06:45   Cataloger was unable to
>   open database **mail/flpilshi.nsf:** RRV bucket is corrupt.
>
> [9371716:00005-00515] 03/12/2015 05:54:54   Error compacting
>   **mail/abc.nsf:** RRV bucket is corrupt.
>
> [9371716:00005-00515] 03/12/2015 05:54:54   Error opening
>   **mail/abc.nsf:** RRV bucket is corrupt.

I understand that i can have expression like "database (.*?) RRV" to grab the value from

> [5439570:00009-01286] 03/03/2015 10:17:31   Error checking database
>   **mail/flpilshi.nsf:** RRV bucket is corrupt.

But i would still like to find out if there any single regrex expression that i can use to just grab the value right before the sentence "RRV bucket is corrupt."?

Thanks for help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're quite close. Something like:

```
/([^ ]+) RRV bucket is corrupt/
```

should get you what you need; it simply grabs all non-space characters that appear before that phrase.

However, that won't get the filename in cases like:

> [8454294:00002-00001] 03/14/2015 02:01:25 RnRMgr: Error encountered while scanning database mail/abc.nsf for events: RRV bucket is corrupt.

If you're specifically wanting the filename, it might be better to tailor the regex to just look for those:

```
/ ([^ ]+\.nsf)/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(\/|\b)(\S+)(?:\s+for \S+)?(?=\:\s+RRV)` regex to get the values, and combine values of the 1st and 2nd groups.

See [example here](https://regex101.com/r/eM8tG8/1).
Output:

```
Match 1: 
 Group1: 
 Group2: mail/abc.nsf

Match 2: 
 Group1: 
 Group2: mail/abc.nsf

Match 3:
 Group1:
 Group2: mail/abc.nsf

Match 4:  
 Group1:
 Group2: mail/abc.nsf

Match 5:  
 Group1:
 Group2: mail/flpilshi.nsf

Match 6:  
 Group1: /
 Group2: notes09/mail/abc.nsf

Match 7:
 Group1:
 Group2: mail/flpilshi.nsf

Match 8:
 Group1:
 Group2: mail/abc.nsf

Match 9: 
 Group1:
 Group2: mail/abc.nsf
```